# Branching on a range of integers in K?

Tags: kframework

I read in the documentation that one can write a rule

```
syntax Exp ::= randBounded(Int, Int)
rule randBounded(M, N) => I
  requires M <=Int I andBool I <=Int N
  [unboundVariables(I)]
```

I would like `randBounded(4,6)` to return some random integer. However, when I try it, it returns an integer `V0` and sets constraints `V0 <=Int 10 ==K true`.

Is there a way, instead, to generate explicit branches for every integer in a range?

e.g. I would like to have `--search` produce 3 configurations:
One for each Integer 4, Integer 5 and Integer 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the expansion you suggest is not possible with `--search` so you cannot get the *exact* three configurations.  However, if you don't actually need those precise configurations, but instead want to be able to reason on their properties, performing (symbolic) execution (using the haskell backend) using this rule somehow comprises all three configurations.

Comment: Ah, I see. How does the symbolic execution work? I had previously been manually implementing the symbolic rules. How does one make use of the built-in symbolic execution?

Comment: Just to answer my own comment, it seems declaring any value as an unbound variable `[unboundVariables(I)]` suffices to let K reason symbolically.